# Trying to merge two arrays, while sorting into third one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a homework that is essentially two arrays that have to be sorted into one. This has the caveat of not combining and then sorting. In other words, I have to go through the two arrays at the same time, but then making a third array from that, which is sorted. I am a bit confused as to how it is possible to search two arrays a the same time, and looking for the lowest value and moving it to the third array.

Can someone show me an example of how something like this can be done? I am confused by it.

Thanks all.

The following are some of the details.

•   The two parameter arrays should not be changed as a result of calling the function.  This is a good practice overall.
•   You may not simply append the two arrays and then sort the result.  Instead, you should be examining each element of the arrays in turn to see which one is smaller.
•   Return a newly created array with the proper contents.
•   The time to execute your algorithm should be directly proportional to sum of the number of elements in both input arrays.

And yes, the arrays are sorted, but I have to go through and find the lowest of value of the two arrays, and then add it to the third array, followed by the second lowest value out of the two arrays, and on and on.....

Comment: Are both arrays sorted already?

Comment: The two input arrays are sorted already? The [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) is quite trivial

Answer (score 1):

If the two arrays are already sorted, and you are ordering them into an empty array,
there is no faster method than the simplest-

```
function insorter(A, B){
    var C= [], LA= A.length, LB= B.length, i= 0, j= 0, k= 0;
    while(i<LA && j<LB){
        while(A[i]<B[j]){
            C[k++]= A[i++];
        }
        while(B[j]<= A[i]){
            C[k++]= B[j++];
        }
    }
    if(i<LA) C.splice(k, 0,A.slice(i));
    else if(j<LB) C.splice(k, 0,B.slice(j));
    return C;
}


var a= [10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49], 
b= [0, 3.5, 7, 10.5, 14, 17.5, 21, 24.5, 28, 31.5, 35, 38.5];
insorter(a, b);
```

/*  returned value: (Array)
0,3.5,7,10,10.5,13,14,16,17.5,19,21,22,24.5,25,28,28,31,31.5,34,35,37,38.5,40,43,46,49
*/

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

and then use the .sort() method, I do not understand what you mean by the fact that you have to go through the 2 arrays at the same time.

Comment: See the updated question. This might be a good method in general, but it's specifically prohibited here.

Comment: Yup, I agree, but the fact that the arrays are sorted was just posted up